# javascript array - adding entries

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript array called mystack, for each recordNo, I want to set up a set of lat/lon values for entities "Source1" and "Source2",  but I am having trouble getting the syntax just right. recordNo is a numeric database record id (eg: 1,2,3)

```
    mystack = {};

    mystack[recordNo {"Source1" } ] = 
    [
        {   
            "lat": 123,
            "lon": 456
        }
    ]


    mystack[recordNo {"Source2" } ] = 
    [
        {   
            "lat": 123,
            "lon": 456
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can never say `recordNo {"Source1" }` in JavaScript. However, since you didn't say what you want, we can't tell what you should do instead.

Comment: `mystack` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 5):

use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

eg:

```
   var sports = ["soccer", "baseball"];
   sports.push("football", "swimming");
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was mixing up arrays and objects. I think I want `myStack[recordNo]["Source1"] = { "lat": 123, "lon": 456 };`

If this is the case, then you can do the following:

```
var myStack = [];
var recordNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];          // list of record numbers
for (var recordNo in recordNumbers) {
    myStack[recordNo] = {};
    var sources = ["Source1", "Source2"];  // list of sources

    for (var source in sources) {
        myStack[recordNo][source] = { "lat": 123, "lon": 456 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add non-numerical properties to arrays. Use an object instead.

Comment: Right track JN!  I was mixing up arrays and objects. I think I want myStack[recordNo]["Source1"] = { "lat": 123, "lon": 456 };

Comment: There are still two flaws in your code: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over array entries, you might be traversing other properties as well. And the nature of `recordNumbers` somehow suggests to use an object for `myStack`, not an array.

Comment: starting to catch on. I wll give it a try,,,